# Python: Check if element is less than the next elements

Tags: python, list, numbers

I want to check each element in the list, if it is smaller than the next after it and print all the numbers that met the condition.

Example:

```
A = [3,1,2,4]
    

A[0] < A[3]

A[1] < A[2] 

A[1] < A[3]

A[2] < A[3]
```

And I don't want to check the last element.

What is the best way to do that?

I tried to do that with for loop:

```
A = [3,1,2,4]
for i in range(0,len(A)-1):
    for j in range(i,len(A)-1):
        if A[j] < A[j + 1]:
            print(A[j],A[j + 1])
    A[j] = A[j + 1]
```

And the result is:

```
1 2
2 4
1 4
```

While the desired results is:

```
3 4
1 2
1 4
2 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix some indices in comparison as well as the ranges. The first counter `i` should iterate from `0` to `len(A)-1` and the second counter should iterate from `i+1` to `len(A)`.

The comparison should happen between `A[i]`, `A[j]` instead of `A[j]`,`A[j+1]`. No need for the last line `A[j] = A[j + 1]` because the counters get incremented automatically.

```
A = [3, 1, 2, 4]
for i in range(0,len(A)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(A)):
        if A[i] < A[j]:
            print(A[i],A[j])
3 4
1 2
1 4
2 4
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you!
How can I count each occurrences of each number?

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```py
arr = [3, 1, 2, 4]

for i, e in enumerate(arr):
    # only if it's not the last element
    if (i + 1) != len(arr):
        if e < arr[i + 1]:
            print(f"arr[{i}] < arr[{i+1}]")

        elif e > arr[i + 1]:
            print(f"arr[{i}] > arr[{i+1}]")

        else:
            print(f"arr[{i}] = arr[{i+1}]")
```

Output

```
arr[0] > arr[1]
arr[1] < arr[2]
arr[2] < arr[3]
```

Comment: @user2733981 Ah sorry, I misunderstood you. Well, I'm glad that it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could try this *enumeate* way, just to save some *slicing*  and some *typing* ... ;-)

If you use *enumerate* it will yield back a *tuple* with index, and number all at once, which is more *elegant*.

```py
for i, a in enumerate(A):
    for j, b in enumerate(A[i+1:]):
        if a < b: print(a, b)

# Output:
3 4
1 2
1 4
2 4
```