# Insert a list of numbers into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, numbers

Following on from my previous question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73255724/python-check-if-element-is-less-than-the-next-elements?noredirect=1#comment129375008_73255724)
I Asked how to check if current element it's smaller than the next elements and count them.

Now, I want to do something else, I want to create a dictionary that stores the values in the following way:

input:

```
 A = [5, 4, 3, 2]
```

output:

```
{'key_5': [4,3,2], 'key_4': [3,2], 'key_3': [1], 'key_2': [0]}
```

Explanation:

- 4,3,2 is less than 5
- 3,2 is less than 4
- 2 is less than 3
- and 2 is the last element and nothing is less than it.

```
A = [5, 4, 3, 2]
res = {}
dp = [0]*len(A)
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(i, len(A)):
        if A[i] > A[j]:
            dp[i] += 1 #Counts how many times each element appears in the list.
            res[f'key_{A[i]}'] = A[j] #Trying to add elements to dictionary.

print(res)
```

And my output is:

```
{'key_5': 2, 'key_4': 2, 'key_3': 2}
```

Comment: can you verify if you wrote the well the explanation ? I can't understand `2 is less than 2` regarding the expected result

Comment: Sorry, 2 is less than 3.

Thank  for your editing my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using dict/list comprehensions:

```
>>> A = [5, 4, 3, 2]
>>> {f"key_{n}": [i for i in A if i < n] or [0] for n in A}
{'key_5': [4, 3, 2], 'key_4': [3, 2], 'key_3': [2], 'key_2': [0]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, champion!
Can the same be done the traditional way? I mean, using "normal" loops?

Comment: Yes, anything written as a comprehension can be written in a more complicated way with a for loop.  In this case you'd have an outer `for n in A` loop to build the dictionary, and an inner `for i in A` loop to build the list for a given key.

Comment: The thing that's missing in your original code is that you want a list as the result, but you never actually created a list.